# How to create PDU concatenated sms?

Tags: sms, pdu, smspdu

Hi I am writing a pdu and im so confused on generating user data. I found an example

0041000C913619873721670000A0050003000301**986F79B90D4AC3E7F53688FC66BFE5A0799A0E0AB7CB741668FC76CFCB637A995E9783C2E4343C3D4F8FD3EE33A8CC4ED359A079990C22BF41E5747DDE7E9341F4721BFE9683D2EE719A9C26D7DD74509D0E6287C56F791954A683C86FF65B5E06B5C36777181466A7E3F5B0AB4A0795DDE936284C06B5D3EE741B642FBBD3E1360B14AFA7E7**

which will send the string "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam, qui" the bold letter on pdu.

i have a pdu encode created in .net which matches the other online encoder and engnick.blogspot.com/2011/09/gsm-7bit-part-of-pdu-packencoding.html

which results to this:

**CCB7BCDC06A5E1F37A1B447EB3DF72D03C4D0785DB653A0B347EBBE7E531BD4CAFCB4161721A9E9EA7C769F7195466A7E92CD0BC4C0691DFA072BA3E6FBFC9207AB90D7FCB4169F7384D4E93EB6E3AA84E07B1C3E2B7BC0C2AD341E437FB2D2F83DAE1B33B0C0AB3D3F17AD855A583CAEE741B142683DA6977BA0DB297DDE9709B058AD7D3**

when I try to do this
0041000C913619873721670000A0050003000301**CCB7BCDC06A5E1F37A1B447EB3DF72D03C4D0785DB653A0B347EBBE7E531BD4CAFCB4161721A9E9EA7C769F7195466A7E92CD0BC4C0691DFA072BA3E6FBFC9207AB90D7FCB4169F7384D4E93EB6E3AA84E07B1C3E2B7BC0C2AD341E437FB2D2F83DAE1B33B0C0AB3D3F17AD855A583CAEE741B142683DA6977BA0DB297DDE9709B058AD7D3**

it sends a wrong string. who can I generate a pdu data same the example?

Answer (score 0):

You gotta send multiple messages by using UDH.
ESM CLASS attribute attribute has to have a value of "64", or "67" for unicode messages.
Also, the beginning of the must contain a hex of the identifier of the message like this:

05 00 03 CC 02 01 [ message 1 text ] 
05 00 03 CC 02 02 [ message 2 text ]

http://www.activexperts.com/activsms/sms/multipart/
http://www.integrat.co.za/wiki/images/1/16/SMPP_v3_4_ESM_Class.pdf
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS#PDU_Mode_SMS

Note that each message will be 3 letters shorter than the standard length of your message datacoding.